# How do I add a number to a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, integer

In my code I have a hash, each one with a set value of 0, after running through the code, I would like it to display "1", but it only displays a 0. Can anyone help, and please explain my error and why it didn't work.

```
puts "Hello!, and welcome to the 'Coin Calculator V1.0', please enter a value."

  coin_value = gets.to_i
  coin_num = {"quarters" => 0,"dimes" => 0,"nickels" => 0,"pennies" => 0}

  if coin_value>25
    coin_value-25
    coin_num["quarters"]+1 // **basically, how do I add an integer value to the old integer?
    puts coin_num["quarters"]

end
```

Comment: Just do `coin_num["quarters"] = coin_num["quarters"] + 1`  with syntactic sugar `coin_num["quarters"] += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
coin_num["quarters"] = coin_num["quarters"] + 1
```

which can be shortened using the `+=` operator (addition assignment):

```
coin_num["quarters"] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel really sill for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your arithmetic expressions changes anything.

```
coin_value - 25
```

That evaluates to 25 less than `coin_value`; if you printed it out or assigned it somewhere, you would see that.  But since you don't do anything with the value, it just gets thrown away and nothing happens. Certainly, `coin_value` doesn't change.

Similarly,

```
coin_num["quarters"] + 1
```

evaluates to one more than the current value of `coin_num["quarters"]`, but doesn't change anything.

If you want to change the value of a variable - any variable, whether a simple scalar like `coin_value` or an element of a Hash or Array - you have to use an *assignment statement*.  You need an `=`, and the variable you want to change has to be on the left hand side of that `=`:

```
coin_value = coin_value - 25
coin_num['quarters'] = coin_num['quarters'] + 1
```

Ruby does define shorthand operators for modifying a variable using a simple expression involving that same variable's previous value:

```
coin_value -= 25
coin_num['quarters'] += 1
```

But you're still using `=` - it's just part of a compound assignment operator now.